# replace values in the columns of a file based on matching values of first column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a question in **awk** about replacing some values in two columns in file1 by the values in file2 when the values in first column match.

Here's an example:

I have:

- `file1`

  ```
  A 2012 3
  B 2012 4
  C 2012 9
  D 2012
  E 2012 7
  F 2012
  ```
- `file2`

  ```
  D 2007 12
  F 2009 8 
  G 2000 4
  ```

The desired output is when values in column 1 matches I want the values in column 2 and 3 to be replaced by the values that are in the file2 as shown below:

- Desired output:

  ```
  A  2012  3 
  B  2012  4  
  C  2012  9 
  D  2007  12
  E  2012  7  
  F  2009  8
  ```

I used this code and I know that there's something wrong with it

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\t"}
    FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;b[$1]=$3; next}
    FNR>=1{if(a[$1]){print $0 }else{print $1, a[$1], b[$1] }}
    ' file2 file1
```

because when I used this code the output that I obtained is:

```
A  2012  3 
B  2012  4  
C  2012  9 
D  2012    
E  2012  7  
F  2012
```

which is the same as `file1`.

Can anybody explain to me what is wrong in this code or suggest alternative solution, please?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But why are you using `FS=","` if both your files are tab or space-separated?

Comment: Thank you for this remark! I didn't pay attention to this mistake, I corrected it and wrote the code as follow ```awk 'BEGIN{FS=" ";OFS="\t"}
     NR==FNR{col2[$1]=$2;col3[$1]=$3;next}
     FNR>=1{if ($1 in col2) {$2=col2[$1];$3=col3[$1]} else {$1=$1}}1' file2 file1```and it worked well. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The problem is two-fold.

- First, you are setting the input field separator to `,` whereas you stated that the input is space-separated. Then, none of your field-based operations will work correctly. If the input is space-separated, you actually don't need to set `FS` at all, because `awk` by default splits input lines at "whitespace" (i.e. any number of immediately consecutive spaces and tabs).
- The second problem lies in your condition `if (a[$1])`. This is true if the first column value of the current line in `file1` is also present in `file2`, but in your code, you would then print the unchanged line from `file1` instead of substituting the values from `file2`, which you actually want.
- Also, your use of `print $0` prints the input line unaltered with the same field separators as read from `file1`, thereby ignoring the `OFS="\t"` directive for these lines.

Instead, use the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
     NR==FNR{col2[$1]=$2;col3[$1]=$3;next}
     FNR>=1{if ($1 in col2) {$2=col2[$1];$3=col3[$1]} else {$1=$1}}1' file2 file1
```

The `$1=$1` will force `awk` to re-build the line using the actual output field separators so that the space will be correctly replaced by `\t`.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but the thing is that the separator in my case is not the ```,``` the separator is the space. I tried the code that you sent me, but it gave me the same result as before :/

Comment: I see. In that case, however, your original `FS=","` was wrong. In fact, if your input is space-separated, you don't need to set the field separator at all; `awk` by default splits input lines at "whitespace" (i.e. any number of immediately consecutive space and tab). I will adapt the answer

Comment: I just saw your comment under the original question. If this solution worked for you (after adapting the FS), please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.